# Connect to BLE peripheral Windows 10

Tags: windows, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is it possible to connect to my custom BLE peripheral device (it implements non standard services/characteristics) on Windows 10 and read/write GATT characteristics? What technology is available - Windows 10 SDK, Xamarin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can use the standard Windows APIs in order to read/write GATT characteristics. You can choose among the Win32 APIs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh450825(v=vs.85).aspx) and the newer Windows RT APIs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.aspx) which are mostly wrappers around the Win32 APIs.

The only requirement I'm aware of is that your custom BLE peripheral device must implement pairing functionality ("Just Works" or "Passkey Entry").

Comment: Thanks. Will that work also on Windows 10 phones and tablets?

Comment: Yes the same WinRT classes are available for Windows Phone as well, since it's part of the Universal Windows Platform.